# Wi-Fi Ubuntu driver unclaimed after installing driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, intel

When running `lshw -C network` I get this for the Wi-Fi adapter (USB tethering works fine) :

```
*-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: 28:df:eb:22:2c:0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.0.9-060009-generic firmware=71.058653f6.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-71.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600324c000-600324ffff
```

So I tried installing the corresponding driver from Intel (https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) copying the ucode file into `/lib/firmware/` and rebooted system.

Still the same message and no Wi-Fi.
This laptop used to be a Windows laptop, I erased windows and installed brand new Ubuntu 22.04, kernel v15

I would appreciate any pointers / possible resolution

Edit #1 :

output of modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl :
[paste bin link, output too big for askubuntu](https://pastebin.pl/view/ec3d7458)

Edit #2:

Tried upgrading the kernel to 6.0.9, still not working. however it did go from unclaimed to DISABLED

Edit #3: Replaced output link for dmesg for output with new kernel, replaced lshw output by output with new kernel

Edit#4:
Backport is not installed

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's see the same command from kernel version 6.0.9, please.

Comment: May we see: `sudo dkms status` if backport is installed, remove it: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and tell us if: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` still returns the same errors.

Comment: From your dmesg: *iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Hardware error detected. Restarting.* The only possibility I can conceive of is a hardware issue. Does it work as expected in Windows? Or some other Linux version?

Comment: it worked before i switchd to ubuntu, i'm gona install windows and let you know

Comment: it does work on windows

Comment: I regret that I have no further suggestions. Sorry.